# Why do they call it "grinding"?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

**Poker:** I'll grind until I have 20k

**PC game:** I spent all night grinding for that level-up

What exactly does it mean and when else can I use it? What are some other examples of it?

And what is the etymology? Is it related to grinding gears? Or grinding joints (arthritis)?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nose_to_the_grindstone ~ I expect it is related to this common idiom, which means to work very hard.

Answer (score 2):

I think it refers to grinding grains, which is a long time consuming job. Women used to spend a large portion of their day grinding the wheat to make the family bread. it is dull repetitive work.

> Grinding with object Reduce (something) to small particles or powder by crushing it.
>
> ‘grind some black pepper over the salad’
>
> ‘she ground up the rice prior to boiling’
>
> 1.1 Sharpen, smooth, or produce (something) by crushing or by friction. ‘power from a waterwheel was used to grind cutlery’
>
> 1.2 Operate (a mill or machine) by turning the handle. ‘she was grinding a coffee mill’
>
> 1.3  (of a mill or machine) work with a crushing action. ‘the old mill was grinding again’

source https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grind

And source for how much time was taken:

> Respect for our ancestors! To feed a family, someone had to do this
> for a couple of hours—every day. Even taking into account that they
> would have more experience, that was still a lot of work and very
> straining on your body.

source: https://skeptoid.com/blog/2016/06/05/grinding-grains/